# Can't use default Terminal theme on my MacBook Pro Lion

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, macbook-pro, themes

I have my terminal settings like so:

On startup, open: New window with settings - Pro

In settings I have the "Pro" theme selected as "Default"

However, every time I open the terminal it will open according to the settings it had when it was last used, not my default settings.

How do I set it so that it will always use the Default themes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the contents of Preferences > Startup ?

You can specify how new tabs and windows are opened, and what should happen when Terminal is launched.